# How to select on the same column that is getting full outer join on?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

If I have two tables

```
Table A
user_id type
123     tier1
124     tier2

Table B
user_id sub_type
123     sub_tier1
125     sub_tier2
```

I want to `full outer` join them and become

```
user_id type sub_type
123     tier1   sub_tier1
124     tier2   null
125     null    sub_tier2
```

i tried something like

> select coalesce(A.user_id, B.user_id) as user_id, type, sub_type from
>   A full outer join B on A.user_id = B.user_id

but it doesn't work, as it only get subset of `user_id` only instead of combining `user_ids` from both tables

More detail:
I actually ran it with Spark SQL, by using the query above, it actually has much less result comparing doing it in dataframe

> tablea.join(tableb, "user_id", "full")

Comment: Which database system are you using? This is the correct result for a full outer join. What is your expected result?

Comment: ^ read the question expected result is there

Comment: Please indicate the database and post the *full query* you are most likely doing outer join mistake number one which is subsequently doing a `where` on the result which removes NULL rows

Comment: sorry i just updated my question with more detail

Comment: me too facing the same issue in spark dataset. In spark shell output is as expected but not in spark dataset. Did you get any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any issues here. Please refer the below snippet

```
WITH tablea (user_id, type) 
     AS (SELECT '123', 
                'tier1' 
         UNION 
         SELECT '124', 
                'tier2'), 
     tableb (user_id, sub_type) 
     AS (SELECT '123', 
                'sub_tier1' 
         UNION 
         SELECT '125', 
                'sub_tier2') 
SELECT COALESCE(a.user_id, b.user_id) AS user_id, 
       type, 
       sub_type 
FROM   tablea a 
       FULL OUTER JOIN tableb b 
                    ON a.user_id = b.user_id; 

USER_ID |TYPE   |SUB_TYPE 
123     |tier1  |sub_tier1
124     |tier2  |(null)   
125     |(null) |sub_tier2
(Complete, 3 rows buffered in 0:00.9)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment I was also facing similar issue. I renamed joining keys and issue resolved. Try renaming user_id column. Let me know outcome.